# Why isn't the program working as a verification system with auto role in a discord bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Please see the code below, I made for the verification thing.I want a program that when a new user will come to the server and type `msg:verify` I will get a reaction verification thing to do and if it doesn't react in 15 secs the program will terminate, also if other user react in place of the user who asked for the verification nothing will happen, and after the verification user will get a role automatically by the bot ,and the role is called 'members'.the code is in python. The program works till reacting after that nothing happens so please help.thanks to all for your help!!

````
async def verify(ctx):
        #define the reactions
        reactiontypes = ["", "❎"]
        #delete the users message ("msg:verify")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        #create the embed...
        embed = discord.Embed()
        embed.title = "Verification!"
        embed.description = "Click the :bell: down below to get yourself verified!"
        embed.colour = discord.Colour.gold()
        #send the message and have "verifymsg" contain the sent message object
        verifymsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        #add reactions that the user can click to verify (the first one is the bell, the second one is the x)
        await verifymsg.add_reaction(reactiontypes[0])
        await verifymsg.add_reaction(reactiontypes[1])
        #a function that will make sure that the user that later can react actually is the person that requested to verify themself
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author
        #"try" is necessary to catch eventual error
        try:
            #wait for the user to react, also set a timeout on 15 seconds for the user to answer
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=15, check=check)
        #if the user didn't react within 15s
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            #delete the verificaiton message
            await verifymsg.delete()
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Timed out", description="You didn't react in time!", colour=discord.Colour.red()))
        #if the user DID answer within time
        else:
            #delete the verificaiton message
            await verifymsg.delete()
            #check if the bell was clicked
            if str(reaction.emoji) == reactiontypes[0]:
                #get the member role
                role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=744014055248887890)
                #add the member role to the user
                await ctx.author.add_roles(role)

                await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You have been verified", description="You are now verified, and can access this server!", colour=discord.Colour.green()))
            #if another reaction than the bell was clicked
            else:
                await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You were not verified", description="You did not click the :bell:, please retry!", colour=discord.Colour.red()))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this code & it works for me. Are you getting any errors at all?

Also, are you sure your bot has the permissions to add roles (`manage_roles`), and that a role with that id exists in the server this is being called in?

Lastly, make sure the role you're trying to add is **below** your bot's role in the role hierarchy. A bot can **not** add a role that is placed higher than it's own role, "it's own role" being the role that gets created when your bot joins the server. The role holds the name of your bot, and your bot should automatically have it assigned.

In case the role is higher than your bot's role, all you need to do is drag it down.